# How does Python 3.10 match compares 1 and True?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, python-3.10

[PEP 622, Literal Patterns](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0622/#literal-patterns) says the following:

> Note that because equality (__eq__) is used, and the equivalency between Booleans and the integers 0 and 1, there is no practical difference between the following two:
>
> ```
> case True:
>     ...
>
> case 1:
>     ...
> ```

and `True.__eq__(1)` and `(1).__eq__(True)` both returns True, but when I run these two code snippets with CPython, it seems like `case True` and `case 1` are not same.

```
$ python3.10
>>> match 1:
...     case True:
...         print('a')  # not executed
... 
>>> match True:
...     case 1:
...         print('a')  # executed
... 
a
```

How are `1` and `True` actually compared?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looking at the pattern matching specification, this falls under a ["literal pattern"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0634/#literal-patterns):

> A literal pattern succeeds if the subject value compares equal to the
> value expressed by the literal, using the following comparisons rules:
>
> - Numbers and strings are compared using the == operator.
> - The singleton literals None, True and False are compared using the is
>   operator.

So when the pattern is:

```
 case True:
```

It uses `is`, and `1 is True` is false. On the other hand,

```
case 1:
```

Uses `==`, and `1 == True` is true.

Comment: I didn't know that PEP would be overwritten by Superseded-By. Thank you for your answer!